# NSManagedObject subclass does not confirm to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, protocols

I have `NSManagedObject` sublclass and i want them to confirm to my custom protocol `JSONInitializable`
There is my protocol:

```
protocol JSONInitializable {
  static func getAllEntities <T: NSManagedObject>(persistenceController:  PersistenceController) -> [T]
}
```

And my `NSManagedObject` sublclass function that causes error:

```
class CDShipment: NSManagedObject, JSONInitializable {    
class func getAllEntities(persistenceController: PersistenceController) -> [CDShipment] {
  let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CDShipment")
  let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "managedNumber", ascending: true)
  request.sortDescriptors = [sorter]
  do {
    let results = try persistenceController.mainMoc?.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [CDShipment]
    return results
} catch {
    print("Error while getting all CDShipments")
  return []
 }
}
}
```

Error:

1. Protocol requires function 'getAllEntities' with type ' (PersistenceController) -> [T]' (aka '<τ_1_0> PersistenceController -> Array<τ_1_0>')
2. Candidate has non-matching type ' (PersistenceController) -> [T]' (aka '<τ_0_0> PersistenceController -> Array<τ_0_0>')

I can't understand, what the problem.